# Python While loop to calculate smallest common multiple

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This is meant to calculate the smallest common multiple of 1-20.

I can't seem to figure out why the while loop won't end. Can anyone help me out?

```
i = 1
j = 1
factors = 0
allfactor = False
while allfactor == False:
    while j < 21:
        if i % j == 0:
            factors = factors + 1
            j = j + 1
        else:
            break
    if factors == 20:
        allfactor = True
        break
    else:
        i = i + 1
        j = 1
        factors = 0
```

Comment: @poke: You should post that as the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least common multiple of the numbers 1..20 is **232792560**.

To get to that number you just need to look at the numbers 1 to 20. You need at least all prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 and 19.

In addition, you need another 2 to calculate 4, and two more 2s for 16. To get a 9 you also need another 3.

So you end up with:

```
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 = 232792560
```

And you can easily confirm that using Python:

```
>>> all(map(lambda x: 232792560 % x == 0, range(1, 21)))
True
```

I.e. all numbers are divisors of said number; and per the proof above (its construction) there is no smaller number.

Comment: Thanks! That's really cool. I'm more interested in why the code doesn't run, though, since I'm trying to learn Python.

Comment: Your code does work, it just takes *ages* until `j` reaches `232792560`.

Comment: You’d usually solve such a problem by generating prime numbers first, as you only ever need to check prime numbers for factorization. To get an idea for that, see my answer to a [similar problem](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23447/484) which calculates the prime numbers in a first step and then allows you to quickly prime-factorize numbers (it’s the other way around than LCM).